# I cannot save the highscore in android studio

Tags: android

I have an issue with saving highscore on a android studio game project. I tried almost everything from this platform about this issue or from another sites but nothing worked. In game i can make points shoot the birds but when i'm die, on the home screen highscore remain 0 and i don't know how to fix it. I will attach an printscreen with the code and i hope to help me please. Thank you in advance and i'm sorry if i didn't express the problem very clear.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjwfN.png)

Comment: You/re getting the highscore, then rewriting it immediately for some reason (not needed, but not hurting anything).  Are you ever writing it when someone actually makes a high score?  Because you didn't add that code, so we have no idea if you are.

Comment: Also, in the future, copy paste your code here, don't use a screenshot

Comment: what do you mean exactly? The game is singleplayer, i don't use a database so it's just me as user. Can you give me please some hints to solve the problem?

Comment: @FrankieTroy It is not a good practise to keep all data in "SharedPreferences." You can do your assignment this way, but it will cause many errors in the future. Instead, attempt to learn more ways to accomplish such a task.